# Cannot print or access char * inside a function

Tags: c

The code below does not print nor return the *char * temp* which I am trying to retrieve from a text file containing a matrix of the form:

```
    4
spQ77377.1  0.000000  0.776030  0.781073  0.804880
spO91086.1  0.776030  0.000000  0.564157  0.559756
spP04578.2  0.781073  0.564157  0.000000  0.302724
spO12164.1  0.804880  0.559756  0.302724  0.000000
```

The whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * const getField( char lineBuffer[255], int field ) {
    printf( "\n " );
    static char temp[30];

    int f = 0;
    for( int i = 0; lineBuffer[i]!='\n' ; i++ ) {
    
        if( f == field && lineBuffer[i] != ' ' ) {
            temp[i] = lineBuffer[i];
            printf( "%c", temp[i] );
        }
        if( lineBuffer[i] == ' ' && lineBuffer[i+1] == ' ' ) {
            printf( "||" );
            f++;
        }
        if( f > field ) {
            printf( " break " );
            printf( "*%s*", temp );
            fflush(stdout);
            return temp;
        }
    }
    return "!";
}

int main() {

    FILE *matrixStream;
    matrixStream = fopen( "outfile", "r" );
    if ( matrixStream == NULL ) {
        printf( "\n\tERROR FILE NOT FOUND!\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    char lineBuffer[255];  
    fseek( matrixStream, 0, SEEK_SET );
    int line = 0;

    char ** field1 = malloc( 4 * sizeof( char *) );
    while( fgets( lineBuffer, 255, matrixStream ) ) {
        if( line != 0 ) {
            printf( "\n line = %d ", line-1 );
            if( line == 1 ) {
                field1[line-1] = malloc( 30 * sizeof( char ) );
                strcpy( field1[line-1], getField( lineBuffer, 1 ) );
            }
        }
        line++;
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    fclose( matrixStream );
    
    return 0;
}
```

My objective is to have the function *getField()* to return a certain field or column (provided in argument as *int field*) for a line in the matrix.

For now, I only have the following output and can not seem to understand the problem, there are no error message during compilation with the options -Wall -pedantic. Here is the exact output:

```
 line = 0 
 ||0.000000|| break **
 line = 1 
 line = 2 
 line = 3
```

The value of *char * temp* is not printed between the * characters as it should be.

Thank you in advance for any help or advice you can provide.

Comment: Have you considered using `strtok()` instead of rolling your own code for finding fields?

Comment: You're not adding a null terminator to `temp`.

Comment: You don't need `fseek( matrixStream, 0, SEEK_SET );`. When you open a file for reading, you automatically start at the beginning.

Comment: `temp[i] = lineBuffer[i];` Can't use the same index for both arrays when you want any field that is not the 0th field... (Because `temp[30]` is small, it's also possible there's some scribbling outside the array happening.)

Comment: you need 2 indexes. one for the line buffer and one for temp

Comment: I did not know of strtok(), but I will use from now on. Thank for the information Barmar !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to terminate your temp buffer, and to have 2 indexes

```
static char temp[30];
int toff = 0; // temp offset
int f = 0;
for( int i = 0; lineBuffer[i]!='\n' ; i++ ) {

    if( f == field && lineBuffer[i] != ' ' ) {
        temp[toff++] = lineBuffer[i]; // use temp offset
        printf( "%c", temp[i] );
    }
    if( lineBuffer[i] == ' ' && lineBuffer[i+1] == ' ' ) {
        printf( "||" );
        f++;
    }
    if( f > field ) {
        temp[toff] = 0; // 0 terminate
        printf( " break " );
        printf( "*%s*", temp );
        fflush(stdout);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

of course you should also error out if toff > sizeof(temp)

BTW the reason you get nothing is that temp, being static, is initialized to 0 at startup and you never write anything to temp[0] (beacuse you use the line buffer offset). So temp is an empty string always